# sort array of object, then sort array of collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

here is the collection and query [code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aQAs5pJhQEx). Now i want to do two things.

i) *sort* `reportTypes` array objects by `counts` in **descending** order then,

ii) *sort* the **collection** by **total no. of counts** in `reportTypes` array in **descending** order.

iii) then group by `managerId`

i want resultant doc to like this.

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("62441917d12596f96de163a3"),
    "managerId": 2,
    "reportTypes": [
      {
        "reasonId": 100,
        "count": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("62441917d12596f96de163a5"),
    "managerId": 3,
    "reportTypes": [
      {
        "reasonId": 200,
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "reasonId": 100,
        "count": 5
      },
      {
        "reasonId": 300,
        "count": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("62441917d12596f96de163a2"),
    "managerId": 1,
    "reportTypes": [
      {
        "reasonId": 300,
        "count": 4
      },
      {
        "reasonId": 200,
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "reasonId": 100,
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: can you add example document about how you expect the final document to look like?

Comment: yeah sure https://mongoplayground.net/p/wRL0YdS7eUb

Comment: order of collection is different and reportTypes object's order is also different. Collection is sorted in descending order of total no. of counts & reportTypes objects are also sorted in descending order of count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $unwind: "$reportTypes"
},
{
  $sort: {
   "managerId": 1,
   "reportTypes.count": -1
 }
},
{
 $group: {
  _id: "$managerId",
  reportTypes: {
    $push: "$reportTypes"
  },
  cnt: {
    $sum: "$reportTypes.count"
   }
 }
},
{
  $addFields: {
    managerId: "$_id"
 }
},
{
 $sort: {
   cnt: -1
}
},
{
  $project: {
    managerId: 1,
     reportTypes: 1
  }
 }
])
```

Explained:

1. Unwind the reportTypes
2. Sort by managerId and descending by reportTypes.count
3. group with push to form the same objects with sorted arrays per managerId and generate summary count per managerId.
4. addFileds managerId
5. Sort by total count ( cnt)
6. Project only the needed fields

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rWANk5c8V83)

Comment: thanks man for so much effort i can't ask more. But it is not what i am looking. I am really grateful to you.

Comment: Let me know what different is expected?

Comment: yeah, i have added in question's comment section

Comment: check the pg it is same resulting doc as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LmzUHTDcL8m

Comment: add to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243511/discussion-between-shubham-maheshwari-and-r2d2).